# Invalid number error when setting variable

Tags: batch-file

I am using the code from [this thread](http://www.experts-exchange.com/OS/Microsoft_Operating_Systems/MS_DOS/A_4196-Advanced-Batch-File-Programming-TOMORROW-BAT.html) to get tomorrow's date. It is as follows:

```
@echo off

set /a d=%date:~0,2%
set /a m=%date:~3,2%
set /a y=%date:~6,4%

:loop
  set /a d+=1

  if %d% gtr 31 (
    set d=1
    set /a m+=1

    if %m% gtr 12 (
      set m=1
      set /a y+=1
    )
  )
xcopy /d:%m%-%d%-%y% /l . .. >nul 2>&1 || goto loop

echo %d%/%m%/%y%
```

However I am getting the following error:

> Invalid number.  Numeric constants are either decimal (17),
>   hexadecimal (0x11), or octal (021).

Although the in the post's text it says:

> When assigning values to variables, we use using SET /A (rather than
>   just SET) to overcome the problem of attempting to perform octal
>   arithmetic on '08' and '09' later on. This is because leading zeros
>   are trimmed off during arithmetic assignment.

Comment: the date format depends on local/regional settings. What is your locale?

Comment: the date format is dd-MM-yyyy, just as the article assumes.

Comment: If I change the month from August (08) to November (10) it runs just fine.

Comment: and in the day, do you have leading zeros there?

Comment: If there's leading zeros in the day, it runs just fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

assuming, you have leading zeros in day and month:

```
set /a d=1%date:~0,2%-100
set /a m=1%date:~3,2%-100
set /a y=%date:~6,4%
```

Comment: shit works, still not sure though why the original scripts fails on the month and not the day

Comment: @user1151923: Probably because the month was `08` (an invalid octal value) and the day was `30` (a valid decimal value).