# batch script Errror : get the day of the year

Tags: windows, file, date, batch-file, getdate

This script let me get the day of year from the current date in a Windows batch file

i used it since january without problem but this month  the script breaks off unnoticed and show incorrect informations.

This is the error :

```
Invalid number. Numeric constants are either decimal (17),
hexadecimal (0x11) or octal (021) numbers.
```

here is the batch code

```
 @echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "_cmd=Get Day^,Month^,Year^"
for /l %%L in (2020 4 2100)do set "_array_leap_year_=!_array_leap_year_!%%L,"


for /f "tokens=1-3delims= " %%a in ('wmic Path Win32_LocalTime !_cmd! ^| findstr /r "[0-9]"')do (
    set "_yy=%%c"
    set "_mm=0%%b"
    set "_dd=0%%a"
    set "_mm=!_mm:~-2!"
    set "_dd=!_dd:~-2!"
    set _date=!_yy!_!_mm!_!_dd!
    )

    echo/!_array_leap_year_!|findstr /lic:"!_date:~0,4!," >nul && (
    set "_leap_=29" & set "_year_=366" )||( set "_leap_=28" & set "_year_=365" )

    set "_mm_dd_year_=01-31,02-!_leap_!,03-31,04-30,05-31,06-30,07-31,08-31,09-30,10-31,11-30,12-31"
    set /a "_loop=!_mm! * 6"

    for /l %%d in (0 6 !_loop!)do set "_sum=!_mm_dd_year_:~%%d,5!" && (
    if "9!_sum:~,2!" lss "9!_mm!" set /a "_day_year_+=!_sum:~-2!"  )

    set /a "_day_year_+=!_dd!"
    set /a "_remain=!_day_year_! - !_year_!"
    echo/Today: !_date! ^| Day of Year: !_day_year_! ^| Days Remaining: !_remain:-=!
```

Comment: Type `set /?` and check out the `set /A` section; you will find out that leading numbers mark octal ones, so `08` and `09` are invalid numbers then…

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid number error when setting variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18528973/invalid-number-error-when-setting-variable)

Comment: to directly fix your issue, do `set /a "_loop=1!_mm! * 6 - 600"`

Comment: @Gerhard, it did not work , it show me day of the year : 274 but today is : Day 223

Comment: I just ran the script, with that changed line and get `Today: 2020_08_10 | Day of Year: 223 | Days Remaining: 143`

Comment: let me post the complete code in an answer, copy it exactly as is.

Comment: @Gerhard it's worked now  .. i did a little modification before and i did not delete it ... thank you very much .. can you explain me this line :  set /a "_loop=1!_mm! * 6 - 600"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the code exactly as is:

All we changed here is `set /a "_loop=1!_mm! * 6 - 600"` which effectively does `set _loop=108 * 6 - 600` which results in `48` same result as `6 * 8`

```
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "_cmd=Get Day^,Month^,Year^"
for /l %%L in (2020 4 2100)do set "_array_leap_year_=!_array_leap_year_!%%L,"

for /f "tokens=1-3delims= " %%a in ('wmic Path Win32_LocalTime !_cmd! ^| findstr /r "[0-9]"')do (
    set "_yy=%%c"
    set "_mm=0%%b"
    set "_dd=0%%a"
    set "_mm=!_mm:~-2!"
    set "_dd=!_dd:~-2!"
    set _date=!_yy!_!_mm!_!_dd!
    )

    echo/!_array_leap_year_!|findstr /lic:"!_date:~0,4!," >nul && (
    set "_leap_=29" & set "_year_=366" )||( set "_leap_=28" & set "_year_=365" )

    set "_mm_dd_year_=01-31,02-!_leap_!,03-31,04-30,05-31,06-30,07-31,08-31,09-30,10-31,11-30,12-31"
    set /a "_loop=1!_mm! * 6 - 600"

    for /l %%d in (0 6 !_loop!)do set "_sum=!_mm_dd_year_:~%%d,5!" && (
    if "9!_sum:~,2!" lss "9!_mm!" set /a "_day_year_+=!_sum:~-2!"  )

    set /a "_day_year_+=!_dd!"
    set /a "_remain=!_day_year_! - !_year_!"
    echo/Today: !_date! ^| Day of Year: !_day_year_! ^| Days Remaining: !_remain:-=!
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use [this simpler method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31565128/how-to-get-the-day-of-year-in-a-batch-file/31569171#31569171) instead:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set /A i=0, sum=0
for %%a in (31 28 31 30 31 30 31 31 30 31 30 31) do (
   set /A i+=1
   set /A accum[!i!]=sum, sum+=%%a
)

for /F "tokens=1-3" %%a in ('wmic Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Month^,Year') do (
   set /A day=%%a, month=%%b, yearMOD4=%%c %% 4 2>NUL
)
set /A dayOfYear=accum[%month%]+day
if %yearMOD4% equ 0 if %month% gtr 2 set /A dayOfYear+=1

echo %dayOfYear%
```

**EDIT**: *Simpler method added*

This method may be simplified and shorten this way:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "daysPerMonth=0 31 28 31 30 31 30 31 31 30 31 30"

for /F "tokens=1-3" %%a in ('wmic Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Month^,Year') do (
   set /A "dayOfYear=%%a, month=%%b, leap=!(%%c%%4)*(((month-3)>>31)+1)" 2>NUL
)
set /A "i=1, dayOfYear+=%daysPerMonth: =+(((month-(i+=1))>>31)+1)*%+leap"

echo %dayOfYear%
```

Answer (score 0):

You could, of course, use [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) from your [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) too:

```batch-file
@For /F %%G In ('%__AppDir__%WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command ^
 "$NOW=Get-Date;$DOY=$NOW.DayOfYear;$YDR=(Get-Date -Month 12 -Day 31).DayOfYear-$DOY;" ^
 "Write-Host ""_date=$($NOW.ToString('yyyy_MM_dd'))`n_day_year_=$DOY`n_remain=$YDR"""'
)Do @Set "%%G"
@Echo Today: %_date% ^| Day of Year: %_day_year_% ^| Days Remaining: %_remain% & Pause
```